# Send email if script outputs string

Tags: bash, cron, sendmail, grep, pipe

I found this line:

```
sh script.sh | grep 'NO' 2>&1 > grep.log && /usr/bin/mail -s "grep found something" m@mail.com < grep.log
```

which will write the output of script.sh to grep.log and then email that to an email m@mail.com

Is there anyway to remove the part where this wrote to grep.log and simply mail the output of the script without having to write it to a file?

Comment: Yes, but only if you would accept empty mails when grep doesn't find anything

Comment: @MichaelHampton According to `man grep` on my comp grep returns `0` (OK) only when a line is selected.

Comment: Aha, I see someone has demonstrated my point; see Romeo Ninov's answer. That is the way to do it, but you will always get a mail, even when nothing is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could capture output to a shell variable instead of a log file:

```
found_stuff=$(sh script.sh | grep 'NO' 2>&1) &&
    echo "$found_stuff" | /usr/bin/mail -s "grep found something" m@mail.com
```

(Note: the first line must be a plain variable assignment, not `export var=` or `local var=` or `declare var=` or anything like that. In those cases the `&&` depends on the exit status of the `export` etc command, not the `grep`.)

Answer (score 2):

To send directly mails you can use command like this:

```
sh script.sh | grep 'NO' 2>&1 | /usr/bin/mail -s "grep found something" m@mail.com
```